# Почему идут пакеты SSDP при запрете

Tags: linux

Анализируя трафик в своей домашней локальной сети я заметил что у меня постоянно идут запросы SSDP от `192.168.0.180`(мой айпи) на `239.255.255.250` [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полазив в настройках роутера я заметил что у меня вообще выставлен запрет на мультикаст то есть IGMP SSDP и т.п запрещено

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И у меня вопрос почему всё равно идёт трафик на SSDP и как мне это отключить

Comment: Настройки роутера никак не могут повлиять на поведение компьютера. Хоть сетевой кабель перережьте нафиг — компьютер всё равно продолжит отправлять SSDP-пакеты в никуда, если он хочет их отправлять. А почему он их отправляет — это уже ищите среди запущенных у вас приложений. [On Linux, how can I tell which process is sending Ethernet packets?](https://serverfault.com/questions/316666)

Comment: Лично у меня отправкой этих пакетов занимается браузер Chrome/Chromium

Answer (score 1):

Вы запретили роутеру слать мультикаст, а не компьютеру.

В линуксе эти запросы шлют avahi, cups, chrome.

Avahi можно отключить полностью.

Cups в настройке /etc/cups/cups-browserd.conf

В хроме это настройка media router в chrome://flags

Если нажать по пакету в wireshark, то можно посмотреть что именно ищет компьютер.